# Deleting file with unlink()

Tags: php, encoding

I have an Apache server (CentOS), where I host a page. On this page I can upload files and remove them. Uploading and displaying filenames works fine. The thing that is bothering me, is deleting files which contain characters like: Č Š Ž (problem of encoding i guess).

č Č ž Ž š Š.txt is displayed like ÄŤ ÄŚ Ĺľ Ĺ˝ Ĺˇ Ĺ .txt in the uploads folder.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

This is the upload code:

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    // Generate timestamp
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $timeStamp = strtotime("now"); 
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';

    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $timeStamp . "_" . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 


    if( move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){ //source, destination
        echo true;
    }else{
        echo false;
    }

}
?>
```

I decided to replace the special characters in the filename:

```
    $subject = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $search  = array('č', 'Č', 'ž', 'Ž', 'š', 'Š', 'ć', 'Ć', 'đ', 'Đ');
    $replace = array('c', 'C', 'z', 'Z', 's', 'S', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D');    
    $subject = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Comment: Not sure how to solve this, but towards the future; I would suggest cleaning the files names before you store them on the file system.

Comment: This may not work, but you could try to add AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in your apache's httpd.conf That's all I can think of right now.

Comment: @lexalizer : that option is already set to UTF-8 in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Then I would try removing the special characters from the file name, I had a similar issue a while ago while I was uploading files with names written in japanese. How about calling urlencode() on the file name without the extension and then save it on the server? This should work and give you a more elegant solution. You could also hash the file name. So far that's all I can think of.

Comment: What do You use to view the content of the folder?

Comment: @Michas: I use WinSCP to remotely connect to my server.

Comment: It looks Your server works in UTF-8 mode. Try to force WinSCP to use this encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You could even extend your replacement function:

```
function remove_accent($str) 
{ 
  $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ'); 
  $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o'); 
  return str_replace($a, $b, $str); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your upload file code. However it's a good idea not to take the neam of the uploaded file and directly use it. Remove strange charecters or perform utf8 encoding of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I would also encourage flattening special chars (Š => S and so on). I had many problem accessing files/folders with such names. But ideal solution would be to completely regenerate you filename...